# Return the Euler Cycle for a graph with es6

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, ecmascript-6

My algorithm for finding an Euler tour of a digraph, G⃗,  if such a tour exists, starting from some vertex, v.

```
'use strict';

var graph = {
    1: [{val: 2}],
    2: [{val: 3}],
    3: [{val: 5}, {val: 4}],
    4: [{val: 1}],
    5: [{val: 6}],
    6: [{val: 3}]
};

var EulerCyle = (function(G, source) {
    var Cycle = function(v) {
        var u;
        for (let i=0; i<G[v].length; i++) {
            u = G[v][i];
            if (!u.visited) {
                u.visited = true;
                return [u.val].concat(Cycle(u.val));
            }
        }
        return [];
    } 

    var P = [source].concat(Cycle(source));
    var i = 0;
    for (let u of P) {
        i++;
        for (let v of G[u]) {
            if (!v.visited) {
                P = P.slice(0, i) + Cycle(u) + P.slice(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return P;

})(graph, 1);

console.log(EulerCycle);
```